# Does Microsoft provide List of values for INTERIOR.COLOR property?

Tags: excel, colors, vba

I have a simple macro that formats headers, but I want to change the color.

Here is a snippet that contains the *.color* property I want to change:

```
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13434879
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

The **13434879** is a light yellow that I selected from the color palette when I recorded the macro.  Now I want to change to a medium gray, but I can't find an index of these values anywhere.  All searches point to a *.colorindex* property, with values 1-56.  But nothing for this 8-digit property shown above.

**UPDATE:**  I found a third-party link that resolves my initial question of finding the values. So I'll tweak it and ask this: does Microsoft provide these values anywhere?  In any guide or tutorial?  If they choose to use this property when I am recording a macro, I would expect they have values for this property explained somewhere.  Any translation from RGB to these values?

Comment: Can you use RGB values instead?

Comment: It appears I could--however my knowledge of VBA is quite basic and I didn't know of RGB property until searching for this property value.  When I used the Record Macro feature, this is the script Microsoft wrote out, so I expected this was the common method of defining a color.

Comment: I just think that RGB would allow you to specify colors easier.  Here is a link to the MSDN page about the RGB function. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc1dyw8b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: RGB is the way to go because the `ColorIndex` (IIRC) is dependent on the user's palette, which varies (or may vary) across users or machines

Comment: `Color` takes an argument of type Long, which is the return value from the `RGB()` function, so typically it's easier to use `.Color =  RGB(a, b, c)` if you want to tweak the actual color .  There are a few built-in constants for Color such as vbWhite, vbBlue, vbYellow, etc but those are pretty limited.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Davis' Endless Productions has this [page for colors](http://www.endprod.com/colors/216safe.htm) and this [page for grays](http://www.endprod.com/colors/grays.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this site:

[MSDN Color Index for VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840443.aspx)

This site provides a lot more information and tips:

[http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm](http://VBA%20Color%20index%20&%20Tips)

This one is a little more complete:

[http://www.endprod.com/colors/](http://Endprod.com/colors/)

Your color of 13434879 falls between Gray 80 and Gray 81 on this chart.

Comment: This is for the .colorindex property, and only provides values for 56 different colors

Comment: The last link provides all code variations for the available colors.